# Unable to print value of shell variable stored in another variable

Tags: bash

I'm trying to find all variables which match a particular pattern and print their values.

```
test_a="apple"
test_b="banana"
test_c="carrot"
test_d="doughnut"

test_show_all () {
    local i
    for i in ${!test_*}; do
        printf "..$i\n"
    #   printf "..$i-->${$i}\n"
    done    
}
```

The loop is finding the correct variables.
But  if I uncomment the second line of the `for` loop, bash is unhappy with the syntax `${$i}`.  I thought this should work since `$i` holds the name of a variable, so I thought `${$i}` should expand to value of that stored name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The indirect variable reference is `${!var}`. Change your code to

```
printf "..$i-->${!i}\n"
```

and it should work.

Comment: [Bash pitfall #32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#printf_.22.24foo.22)

Answer (score 1):

Not useful now, but in `bash` 4.3, you will also be able to use namerefs.

```
for name in ${!test_*}; do
  declare -n value=$name
  printf "..$name->$value\n"
done
```

As a short cut, if you only want to iterate over the values (without regard to the actual name of the variable), you can use

```
declare -n value
for value in ${!test_*}; do
  printf "..$value\n"
done
```